# Problem with very simple variadic function

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I am trying to use a very simple log function using variadic templates in C++:

```
void log(){}

template <typename T, typename... Types>
void log(T first, Types... arg)
{
    std::cout << first << " ";
    log(arg...);
}

int main()
{
    log(1,2);
    log(3, "four");
    log(5);
    log(6,"seven",8,9,10,11,12);
    log(13,14);

}
```

But in the output I am missing all the last arguments of the log function if the are integers (**2, 5, 12** and **14**) but not if they are strings (**"four"**) !??. Why is that? What I am doing wrong?

```
output: 1 3 four 6 seven 8 9 10 11 13
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/x1JXLNZOWjyp8hM3).  What compiler and command line switches are you using?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/0UsLJL), either. You are just going to have to debug the code to figure out what is happening on the calls that don't work.

Comment: thanks @PaulSanders, it is spooky, I am not aware of using anything special. It is a fresh project in a recently installed Visual Studio 2021 without any further modifications. I also tried with VS2019 and get the same result.

Comment: I can confirm the problem on VS 2019, and there doesn't seem to be any obvious  workaround.  Looks like an MSVC bug, although it's hard to see how such an obvious problem has escaped their attention.

Comment: Agree, It would be crazy if it was actually a bug. In any case, I will get away from variadic functions for now :DD thanks.

Comment: Not necessary a bug, OP doesn't show the `#include` used. `<math.h>` would be problematic. (and as standard `#include` are allowed to include other ones ... :/ ).

Comment: @Jarod42 In my tests, just including `iostream` was enough to trigger the problem, when compiling with MSVC (VS 2019).

Comment: @PaulSanders: `<iostream>` is allowed to include other files (as `<string>` for libstdc++) :/ . C++20 modules should be better :-)

Comment: Related to [are-symbols-from-the-c-standard-library-reserved-in-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68455008/are-symbols-from-the-c-standard-library-reserved-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mystery solved - when compiling with MSVC your choice of the name `log` is clashing with the `log` function in the standard library when there is only one numeric parameter.  Since this doesn't print anything, output is missing.

Just use another name and it works.

Comment: "Fixing" `#include` is also a possibility: using `<cmath>` instead of `<math.h>` (and avoid `using namespace std;`).